# Error when converting dataframe object into int64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

Good day. I am working on 2 dataframes that i will later be comparing, *playersData* & *allStar*. *playersData['Year']* is type int64, while allStar is type object. i tried to convert the *playersData['Year']* using the following code:

```
playersData['Year'] = playersData['Year'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

but it shows error saying:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'
```

the code I used is from the link: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-column-from-object-to-int-in-python

here is reference pics regarding types of my dataframes:

[image: dtypes of 2 dataframes]

Comment: At the end you want all your year data to be intigers or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Dropping all the nan values from the dataset.

```
playersData.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: hi, thanks! it worked, but it is int32, is there any way i can make it int64? or it does not matter when i try to compare it with int64 from my other dataframe?

Comment: It shouldn't matter much but if you want to convert it into int64, you can try this:

```
df = df.astype({'Year': 'int64'})
```


Also, please  do upvote the answer if you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can either drop rows containing NaN values or replace them with a constant (In case there were few other columns containing valuable info, dropping rows might not be a good option).

1. If you want to drop
   `playersData.dropna(inplace=True)` or `playersData = playersData.dropna()`
2. Replacing with a constant (Ex: 0)
   `playersData['Year'].fillna(0, inplace=True)` or `playersData['Year'] = playersData['Year'].fillna(0)`

Comment: Yes. They consider NaN as float64

Comment: Hi, replacing the NaN value with 0 did came in handy when i was trying to convert other column's dtypes, thanks! i have upvoted ur answer, but my reputation is low so it wouldn't show. Have a nice day!